# Как подписать строку в HMAC SHA512

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь портировать питон код в с#

```
key = base64.b64decode(secret)
message = str.encode(path + str(1584970875228), "utf-8")
hmac = hmac.new(key, message, sha512)
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.digest()).decode()
```

Почему то моя подпись отличается от подписи в питон. У меня некорретный, так как не идёт запрос на сервер

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(Credentials.Secret.GetString());
var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
var message = absolutePath + 1584970875228;
var rez = ComputeHash(key, message);


private static string ComputeHash(string apiKey, string message)
{
   var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(apiKey);
   string hashString;
   using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(key))
   {
      var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
      hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
   }
  return hashString;
}
```

Comment: Запустите в отладке и пошагово сравните вычисляемые данные.

Comment: Пробовал, в питоне там бинарные данные

Comment: Ну, как вариант можете переводить в HEX во временную переменную.

Comment: а вы уверены, что проверяете на одинаковых данных? у меня возвращает одинаковый результат

Comment: ну питон возвращает DRXI21Xxd0moQT6e7pDMPruKa9W9ao24mxlwD9NpTYt+EUDe5OhtvTBGECZgzgCXGBxq2CSXM+GNInE0Guk47w==

Comment: @ExplodingKitten а с# dswqFBsaW1ygSH8umJGvg/xtv5GHbNl1T518JBxHJth33nY8Li71zfro/R8wVBttZh5TeJK24xXCxpx5IdKT2Q==

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);
byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path + nonce);
HMACSHA512 hmac = new HMACSHA512(key);
string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(message))
```